# Evaluate and print factorial

Tags: c

Consider the following:

```
double fact(int n)
{
    int i;
    double res = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        res *= i;

    return res;
}

double f = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
{
    printf("%lf \n", fact(2*i + 1));
    f *= (f + 1)*(f + 2);
    printf("%lf \n", f);
}
```

Why does `fact(2*i+1)` results a correct value while `f` results a weird value of `1.#INF00`?

Comment: as far as I can see, `fact()` is a function, `f` is a variable and a meaningless `for` loop in your code. You mind elaborating a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it overflows.

The value of `f` after 16 iterations is bigger than if your code looked like this and your initial `f` was 2:

```
f *= f*f;
```

Which is the same as

```
f = f*f*f
```

So you take a cube 16 times - this is HUGE!

2^3 = 8

8^3 = 512

512^3 = 134217728

...

Comment: But even `f*=(f+1)` overflows. Why?

Comment: Same reason - taking squares 16 times is HUGE... What on earth are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Same behavior of the `fact` function

Answer (score 1):

On the topic of undefined behaviour, the `l` length modifier in `%lf` is only defined for conversion specifiers using *integer* types. If you meant to use `%Lf`, then your argument should be a `long double`. Perhaps you meant to use `%f`, which corresponds to a `double` argument (`float`s end up promoted to `double` when passing them to variadic functions such as `printf`).

As Peter Ivanov explained, your calculations cause an overflow, which IIRC is also undefined behaviour.

As you've probably guessed, you might find a solution to your problem by using the `long double` type (and the corresponding `%Lf` format specifier) throughout your code...